# Program stops responding when initializing a variable

Tags: c, initialization

I'm having a problem that must be idiot, but I can't see why.
the main code reaches the "2test" print and then stops responding at l->n = 0;
This is my first (real) program in C, so my knowledge is small in this language.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "list.h"

int main(){
    TList* l;
    FILE* txt = fopen("arqtxt.txt", "r");
    char aux[80];
    int c = fgetc(txt), x = 0;

    printf("1test");
    TList_Init(l);
    printf("6test");
    while ((c = fgetc(txt)) != EOF){
        printf("%d",c);
        while (!(isalpha(c))) c = fgetc(txt);
        if (isupper(c)) c = c+32;
        if (islower(c)) aux[x++] = (char) c;
        else{
            TList_Insert(l, aux);
            strcpy(aux, "");
        }
    }
    TList_Print(l);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

list.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "list.h"

void TList_Init (TList* l){
    printf("2test");
    l->n = 0;
    printf("3test");
    l->tam = 100;
    printf("4test");
    l->v = malloc(sizeof(TItem)*l->tam);
    printf("5test");

}int TList_Search (TList* l, char* c){
    int i;
    for (i = l->n-1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (strcmp(l->v[i].chave, c) == 0) return i;
    return -1;
}

void InsertSort (TItem* v, int n){
    int i,j;
    TItem aux;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++){
        aux = v[i];
        j = i-1;
        while (j >= 0 && strcmp(aux.chave, v[j].chave) < 0){
            v[j+1] = v[j];
            j--;
        }
        v[j+1] = aux;
    }
}
void TList_Insert (TList* l, char word[80]){
    if (l->n == l->tam){
        l->tam += 100;
        l->v = realloc(l->v, sizeof(TItem)*l->tam);
    }
    char* c = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(word));
    c = word;
    int aux = TList_Search(l, c);
    if (aux != -1){
        l->v[aux].no++;
        return;
    }
    l->v[l->n].chave = c;
    l->v[l->n].no = 1;
    l->n++;
    InsertSort(l->v, l->n);
}



void TList_Print (TList* l){
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x <= l->n; x++)
        printf("%s - %d", l->v[x].chave, l->v[x].no);
}
```

list.h:

```
#ifndef LIST_H_
#define LIST_H_

typedef struct Item{
    char* chave;
    int no;
} TItem;

typedef struct List{
    TItem* v;
    int n, tam;
} TList;

void TList_Init (TList*);
void TList_Insert (TList*, char[]);
void TList_Print (TList*);

#endif
```

output:

```
||=== Build: Debug in EP1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\EP1\main.c||In function 'main':|
C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\EP1\main.c|13|warning: 'l' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
||=== Build finished: 0 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
||=== Run: Debug in EP1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|

-------------- Run: Debug in EP1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\EP1\bin\Debug\EP1.exe
Executing: "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks/cb_console_runner.exe" "C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\EP1\bin\Debug\EP1.exe"  (in C:\Users\Lucas\Desktop\EP1\.)
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 9 second(s))
```

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize the pointer `l` before you pass it to `TList_Init(l);`. Then assigning to `l->n` leads to **undefined behavior** in C language standardese because you use an indeterminate value.

What about making `TList_Init()` returning a *ptr-to-TList* instead?

```
TList *TList_Init (void)
{
    TList *l;

    l = malloc (sizeof *l);
    /* Check l != NULL here ... omitted. */
    printf("2test\n");
    l->n = 0;
    printf("3test\n");
    l->tam = 100;
    printf("4test\n");
    l->v = malloc(sizeof(TItem) * l->tam);
    printf("5test\n");
    return l;
}
```

Comment: but the objective of TList_init is to initialize l, how do I fix it?

Comment: You need to pass the address of `l` and then allocate memory for a `Tlist` in `TList_init()`.

Comment: @ColdLucas Good! The next step would be to upvote and accept the answer(s) that helped you by clicking the up arrow and check-sign.

Comment: Just got 15 rep, now I can upvote your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Jens' correct answer: `TList* l;` initialises a pointer to an address in memory - it does not allocate the memory for `TList` itself, so l most likely points to some random chunk of memory that you should not have access to.

You'd have to either call

```
l = malloc(sizeof(*l))
```

to reserve memory. Remember to call `free(l);` once you're done.

Alternatively declare l not as pointer, but rather as TList:

```
TList l;
[...]
TList_Init(&l);
```

This reserves memory in stack for `TList`, and passes a pointer via `&` to the method, with the proper memory allocated - in this case, you do not need to free the memory, as it's automagically freed once the method in which the variable was declared returns.